# What is "Physical id 0" shown in Psensor?

Tags: 12.04, psensor

My system has a 2nd Generation Core i7 2670QM @2.2ghz with the Linux kernel 3.4. Psensor (I am using it to check my CPU/HDD temp) is showing `Physical id 0` at 50 deg C.

It also shows:

> **Sensor Information**
>
> Id:                          lmsensor coretemp-isa-0000 Physical id 0

I want to know what is `Physical id 0`? Does that mean it's showing the temperature of the installed RAM module or something else?

I would also like to know if the temperature is normal or overheated?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Physical id 0` is referring to your CPU.  The CPU TJmax is 100 degrees Celsius.  So 50 degrees Celsius is normal.  Also  make sure that ambient temperature is good.

Comment: On my i7-4771 it looks like `Physical id 0` = maximum of cores 0-3?

Answer (score 2):

To complete the above answer which is obviously correct, here is the full list of Psensor sensord ids and corresponding type of chips:

- ‘lmsensor coretemp’: Intel CPU.
- ‘lmsensor k10temp’,'lmsensor k8temp’,'lmsensor fam15h_power’: AMD CPU.
- ‘nvidia’ or ‘lmsensor nouveau’: NVIDIA GPU.
- ‘hdd’: hard disk drive.
- ‘amd’: AMD GPU.
- ‘lmsensor C B’: C is the name of the chip, B the name of the adapter.

This information is also available at: https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/faq.html#S_WhatIsTheSensor

Since Psensor 0.7.0.4, the chip name is available in the sensor information window:

[image: Intel Chip]

Some technical information about your CPU is available at: http://ark.intel.com/products/53469, maximal temperature is 100C (Tjunction), so 50C is fine.

Comment: what are temp1 temp2 temp3?