# lm-sensors: From sensors command, what is "Package id 0"?

Tags: command-line, cpu, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

When I run `sensors` on my xubuntu machine, I get the following:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +80.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +80.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +53.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          14.88 V  
curr1:         1.20 A  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  

pch_cometlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +51.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)
```

My computer has 6 CPU cores (shows 12 CPU on htop etc), and the `Package id 0:` is consistently at 75°C or above.

When I unplug my charging cable the temperature goes back down to 45°C or 50°C.

What is `Package id 0`? And should I be worried about +80.0°C for a laptop?

PS: My computer freezes randomly maybe twice in a day and becomes completely unresponsive. I have to use the physical power button to reboot. I think it's caused by temperatures and individual CPUs randomly jump to 80 and back down to 45. This specific question relates to `package id 0` though. I'm wondering if my sensors be malfunctioning...

Comment: Most laptops are *really poorly* pasted from the factory - it's usually so bad it's almost a joke. I would under all circumstances recommend that you re-paste the CPU. If you're not comfortable doing this yourself, get a hold of someone who can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is funny because I have paid extra to get a better quality thermal paste from the manufacturer. And you are right, package shows the maximum temp for the underlying CPUs. Haven't noticed until you've pointed it out.

Comment: Yeah - but thermal paste only lasts so long. I actually repaste once a year if I can get around to it - the paste dries out over time. Cheers! 

Comment: Also, I suspect the reason it reduces temperature when unplugged is that the CPU lowers the frequency to save power - this is quite normal.

Comment: Related question: [What is "Physical id 0" shown in Psensor?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140978/618353)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Package id 0` is used to reference the CPU "as a whole".

[This Intel article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058845/processors.html) explains how the core and package temperatures are measured:

> The processor has different digital thermal sensors to measure the
> temperature. **Core temperature** is measured per core while **package
> temperature** is a weighted average value of individual core
> temperatures reported by software monitoring applications.

However, in practice `Package id 0` will typically have the highest value among cores - or a bit higher.

80.0°C is a bit on the hot side. I would say between 60 and 70°C when idle is OK, and between 80 and 90°C with high CPU load.

If it gets hotter than that, you should try re-pasting your CPU (off-topic here, but search on YouTube).

Comment: Nothing is said about "package id 0" anywhere on SO. This will help others as well.